# Photo editing app iOS

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, uiimageview, pixel

I am trying to make a photo editing application for iOS, but am not sure where to start looking. I have attached an image made in Word... that hopefully simply depicts what I am trying to achieve. It will involved manipulating individual pixels of a shape/image and masking/clipping. WHow should I start and what resources are available to me other than the developer docs?

Cheers

[image: here is the image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not new to programming I would suggest a trial and run kind of approach. If it was me, I would follow a approach like this

**Figuring out what to do/ what not to do**

1. Do I need to develop the tech I want from scratch or can I use some pods ?
2. What are the good reads and example apps - ([Try this](https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/tree/master/SamplePhotoEditingExtension))

**Development approach**

1. Build a photo gallery to pick images from
2. Build a EDIT mode screen
3. Get set of template overlay images
4. Figure out how to overlay them on top of each other
5. Export the final picture as one picture

Answer (score 0):

The developer documentation is essential when it comes to learning new APIs, but sometimes it can be a little overwhelming. You can try reading raywenderlich.com tutorials on Core Image first to get an idea (link [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift)) or find a book on computer graphics. It is essential to understand at least the underlying techniques to efficiently program image processing code. In many cases you'll find there is a more elegant technique than just looping on pixels and modifying one-by-one.

Then you can continue with reading on image compositing using core image for example.